Where to cut self to give blood to another being
Where would be the best place to drain blood. I have a character who gives blood to their Patreon as part of their deal but I’m trying to figure out how they do that. Like most media uses cutting wrists or palms but that seems dumb and like it causes a lot of damage.

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about writing; it's a question of medical nature.

But it’s for writing? It’s for a character

@Fern You're asking for medical information. "For writing" is not a magic incantation that makes question on-topic.. If you asked "How does my character debug the following code " that is still a programming question, not a writing one. Similarly, if you ask "What is a good recipe my character can use " that's again not about writing. See [help/on-topic],

Oh. I thought u could ask anything related to stories and writing and charcters u needed help with. I’m sorry.

@Fern It's for writing but that doesn't mean it's about writing. Research questions for your writing are usually a better fit for the channel dealing with the given topic (history, chemistry, law, farming, whatever). Questions about English tend to be a better fit for one of the two channels about the English language. Questions about worldbuilding should go on Worldbuilding. Focus on what you're asking, rather than why you're asking. You're likely to get better answers from people who know the subject, even if they have very different reasons to know it from those you have.

The medically best places are those used by real world physicians. If you need only a small amount of blood (a drop), prick the finger tip. If you need more, insert a hollow needle into the veins in the crook of the arm (antecubital fossa). Other possible areas are on the back of the hand (less blood and danger of nerve damage) or on top of the foot or any vein you see on your forearm. If you only puncture the vein with a needle, a bit of pressure will close the wound (again, look at how this is done by real world physicians). Any larger cut, such as with a knife, needs to be sewn. Other places on the body, where veins are large and easily accessible, such as the neck, are potentially dangerous (blood loss to the brain).
